# How can i make the border and z-index stay until the end of the transition?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, border

I'm wanting to create a scale but i seem to have a little trouble with my borders and them staying during the scale transition. In my code, the grid has a top and left border and the items have a bottom and right border. Else i would get double borders. Now, if i want to tranform the scale to 1.1 to create a nice popout effect, the borders disappear when i remove my mouse because the hoverstate goes away. Does anyone have an idea how i can keep single borders and still have the borders stay all the way through the transition?

[This is what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbqD8.gif)

```css
.project-grid .grid {
  width: 80%;
  align-self: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  background: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.inner-container:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.project-tile {
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.project-tile .see-more {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.project-tile:hover .see-more {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project-tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
  <div class="flex-wrapper row">
    <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="project-tile span-2">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile span-2">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your code and use outline instead of combined borders and make sur you consider a delay for the z-index on unhover

```css
.project-grid .grid {
  width: 80%;
  align-self: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.project-tile {
  transition: transform .3s,z-index 0s 0.3s; /* updated */
  z-index:1;
}

.project-tile .see-more {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
}

.project-tile:hover .see-more {
  opacity: 1;
}

.project-tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform .3s,z-index 0s 0s; /* updated */
}
/* this will make sure the hovered element will always be on the top */
.project-tile:hover ~ *{
  z-index:1;
  transition: z-index 0s 0s;
}
/**/

.span-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
  <div class="flex-wrapper row">
    <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="project-tile span-2">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-tile span-2">
        <div class="inner-container">
          <h3>SPIL</h3>
          <p>Yeet</p>
          <a href="#noref" class="see-more">Bekijk meer ></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really struggling with this the other day. Every day i lean new css things haha. Thanks for the quick reply!